# Java 8 Wildfly 14 OutOfMemoryError on phase install

Tags: java, java-8, jboss, wildfly

I'm trying yo deploy an application of around 45MB to a Wildfly 14. The deployment goes well if I don't set the enabled flag in the wildfly deployments console, but as soon as I enable the deployed app it throws the below error:

```
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"conciliador-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"conciliador-backend-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war\"
    Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace"}}
```

The wildfly server has the default configuration parameters, is there something I need to tweak or to configure so that the server won't get OutOfMemory?

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: We need the logs entries that came just before your out of memory error and the complete statcktrace if you can find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `-XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1024m` in standalone.conf(for linux environment) file. If you still encounter same error, try increasing 'MaxMetaspaceSize', but 1gb should be enough. -